# iTunes not installing: Partially downloaded

Tags: osx-lion, itunes, software-update

I can't update iTunes and I'm stuck now.

When I run software update, it says that there's an update about iTunes: 10.6.3 (176.9MB)
And it says "iTunes: Partially downloaded (0%)" at the bottom of the software update screen.

I expect Mac to download the files when I click "Install 1 Item" button. The download progress bar shows for a millisecond and and alert is displayed:

```
The update could not be verified. It may have been corrupted during 
downloading. 
The update will be downloaded and checked again the next time that 
Software Update runs.
```

So I checked /Library/Updates folder and I see that there's only the dist file which is an XML file with package information but the software itself is not in there.

I tried deleting all the files under /Library/Updates folder but nothing changed...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried updating from other sources (e.g. app store, downloading a new copy from Apple's website)?

Comment: What @user142485 said: get the full installer from Apple's website.